# warning: comparison between pointer and integer in loop

Tags: c

Just an ordinary task, I want to make array static using C, and write this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int angka[10];

    printf("Masukkan angka sebanyak 10 kali:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < angka; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", angka[i]);
    }

    printf("\nOutput: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < angka; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", angka[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and i got this error

```
PS D:\Materi Kuliah\1031101 DASPRO\Semester 1\Week-14\Review W6-W7> gcc no1.c -o a
no1.c: In function 'main':
no1.c:14:23: warning: comparison between pointer and integer      
   14 |     for (int i = 0; i < angka; i++)
      |                       ^
no1.c:20:23: warning: comparison between pointer and integer      
   20 |     for (int j = 0; j < angka; j++)
```

does anyone know what is happening? i don't really understand why symbol < causing error. i don't get it
i try to searching it in google/stackoverflow but i don't get anything.

Comment: 'i < angka'.......  'angka' is not an int, so cannot be compared to one.  The index of the 'angka' array is, however, an int.  Read up on array indexing and tbe sizeof operator when applied to arrays.

Comment: BTW, that array has automatic storage lifetime, not static.

Comment: A good compiler should be warning you that you're misusing the `scanf` function such that you won't be getting anything assigned to `angka[i]`.

Comment: I am guessing that you want to iterate through the length of the array, but when you use `angka` the way you do, you are comparing the address of the array with an integer, which is not what you want. The length of an array is its size divided by the size of its members, so you want `sizeof angka / sizeof angka[0]`. For `scanf()`, you need to give it the address of an integer to write to, and you are giving it an integer (which it might try to use as a pointer, which would be bad). You want `&angka[i]` to get the address of the i'th integer in `angka`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to determine the length of the array like

```
int l = sizeof(angka)/sizeof(angka[0]);
```

and use it in the for loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
   {
     ...
   }
```

or simply

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
     ...
   }
```

because you know the length of the array

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
for (int i = 0; i < angka; i++)
```

should be
#define SIZE 10
int angka[SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)

as `angka` is a pointer to the 1st item of the array

BTW

```
scanf("%d", angka[i]);
```

Should be

```
scanf("%d", &angka[i]);
```

And checkout the manual page for `scanf` i.e check for the return value

Comment: Technically correct, but bad code. Don't put array length calculations in the loop. Rather put the array length value in a variable right after the array declaration. Otherwise *you will have a bug* when `angka` gets turned into a pointer

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop goes from integer 0 to another integer.
Unfortunately for you, the type of angka is not an integer, it's an array of integers.

What you're trying to do is loop over every element of the array up to its size.

To do that, you need to calculate the length of angka and use THAT as the end of your for loop.

```
int main()
{
    int angka[10];
    int size = sizeof(angka)/sizeof(angka[0]); //This will evaluate to 10

    printf("Masukkan angka sebanyak 10 kali:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", angka[i]);
    }

    printf("\nOutput: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", angka[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The sizeof operator returns the number of bytes of data a variable takes in memory.

So sizeof(angka) will give us the total memory taken by angka (which will be size of the type it contains times the number of elements). In the case on an integer on a 64-bit machine, that's the size of an integer, which is 4 bytes * 10 elements = 40 bytes

Then, sizeof(angka[0]) will give us the total memory taken by the first element of the array. Since the first element of the array is an integer, that's 4 bytes.

We then divide those two, sizeof(angka)/sizeof(angka[0]) = 40bytes / 4bytes = 10, which is the number of elements in our array.

As noted by other answers, your usage of scanf should also be changed :)

Comment: I still don't understand, we use sizeof(angka) to read the size.
but why we can't just puts angka in loop like before? doesn't it read the size of angka too?

Comment: Well the type of angka is int[10] (an array of ten integers), which is a different type from just an integer. For example, which is less, 5, or [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]? That's not a comparison that makes much sense is it? Just putting angka does not give the size. In fact, it'll actually give you the place in memory at which the first element is stored, which, were we to somehow convert to an integer, would be a wild wild number.

Answer (score 0):

In an expression, that has type *array of type* is converted to an expression with type *pointer to type* (with few exceptions) that points to the initial element of the array object . In this expression `i < angka`, array `angka` converted to pointer to `int` and the type of `i` is `int`, hence you are getting warning.

In order to loop over an array, you need the size of that array. To get the size of `angka` array, you can do:

```
size_t sz = sizeof (angka) / sizeof (angka[0]);
```

Note that the *type* of the result of `sizeof` operator is `size_t`.

You can use this expression directly in loop condition statement, like this:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof (angka) / sizeof (angka[0]); i++)
    {
        ....
        ....
```

There is one more problem in your code, look at this `scanf()` statement:

```
scanf("%d", angka[i]);
```

the `scanf()` expects the pointer (address of variable) as argument.
`angka` is an array of integer and `angka[i]` is an integer at `i`<sup>th</sup> index of array. You should pass address of `angka[i]` i.e. `&angka[i]` to `scanf()`. Correct statement is:

```
scanf("%d", &angka[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks bro, i understand it

Comment: Glad to hear it ^_^